# Extract JSON array based on subarray length?

Tags: json, jq

Given

```
{
    "result": {
        "spaces": [{
            "priceschema": {
                "prices": [{
                    "costs": [{
                        "amount": "3"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I'd like to display all `prices` that have more than one costs. I came up with the following jq query, but it returns all costs, even the ones with a single element.

```
{price: .result.spaces[].priceschema.prices[]?} | select((.price.costs[] | length) > 1)
```

Note that `prices` or `costs` may not be present.

Comment: Please revise your question in accodance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't given an example showing the output format you want, all I can suggest is the following:

```
.result.spaces[].priceschema.prices[]
| {price: .}
| select((.price.costs? | length) > 1)
```

Hopefully this will direct you towards the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I don't want based on `prices` length, but `costs` length. Your `select` query is incorrect

Comment: Please revise your Q in accordance with [mcve].  Please make sure the example is informative.

Comment: The question is clear enough; I can't help if you don't read it. Not every question requires a MCV.

Comment: The question may be clear to you but that does not mean it is clear to others.  In fact I could show you at least two plausible interpretations. The example is also uninformative, and does not even show the required format of the answer under any scenario. In future, please abide by the MCVE guidelines.  They are there for a reason.